# Upgraded my project to .net 6 now I have time zone in EF Core with postgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I juste upgraded my web api to .net6 using EFCore and NPGSQL (Postgres).
I had to Set a Switch for my code to work:
`AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);`

Now EFCore Creates my DateTime fields to *'timestamp with time zone'* which breaks everything.

How can I get the old *'timestamp without time zone'* for DateTime Types?

Should I remove the LegacyTimestamp switch?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Consult the breaking changes notes

Comment: I suppose you are talking about those breaking changes: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#breaking-changes but this doesn't help me with EFCore.

Comment: No, the changes here: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html#timestamp-rationalization-and-improvements

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I Fixed it by forcing column type for all DateTime and DateTime? to "timestamp without time zone" by adding the following code in the OnModelCreating of my DBContext.

```
foreach (var property in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                 .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
                 .Where
                 ( p
                   => p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) 
                      || p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?)
                 )
        )
{
  property.SetColumnType("timestamp without time zone");
}
```

Feels like a hack but it works.

Comment: doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I have encountered this bug also.  It appears that EF Core just assumes that there is a time zone, even though the actual database type is `timestamp without time zone`. (in my case it was `entity.HasColumnType` to fix it)  It probably has something to do with my magical incantations of database contexts being ever-so-slightly incorrect, but such is the nature of frameworks.  Obfuscation for all!

Comment: Use this loop at the end of "OnModelCreating" void before calling "OnModelCreatingPartial" and it works for all items